# Optmizing query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I have table with around 70 000 rows. There is 6000 rows that i need to find, change, and save (i must do this often, few tiems a week). Curently, i am doing it like this, and it las more than 2 minutes to finish: (any advice? :( )

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM my_table WHERE meta_key = 'key' AND meta_value LIKE '%something%'")or die(mysql_error());

  $new = "soemthing something";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $old = unserialize($row['meta_value']);
    $new_meta_r = str_replace($old['color'],$new,$old);
    $new_meta = serialize($new_meta_r);

    $update_meta = mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET meta_value = '$new_meta' WHERE meta_key = 'key' AND meta_value LIKE '%something%'")or die(mysql_error());
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to store the pkeys from the first query in an array, and then do the updates with an IN() clause instead of LIKE?

Comment: Consider using MongoDB, not SQL for such high amounts of data

Comment: You would need an Id column (is meta_key unique?) and do an update WHERE Id=<selected id>

Comment: @Дамян Станчев what do you mean "pkeys"? I should take id's from first query, and do updates with IN?

Comment: @SomeoneS we need more information, index? engine? Mysql version?

Comment: @CyberDude yes, meta_key is always "key". Regarding MongoDB, i curently use WP, so i dont want to play with experimenting.

Comment: It looks a bit odd that you are able to lookup in a "serialized" column yet you need to "deserialize" it in order to change it... what's that all about?

Comment: @jcho360 engine: MyISAM, version 5.5.24, index: have no idea

Comment: @SomeoneS you query is simple so there is not too much to optimize there, but you can optimize your DB, we need to see the explain comman and show create table, I think that adding a fulltext index will help

Comment: @CyberDude php multidimensional arrays are serialized (and are in database)

Comment: 70 000 rows is not a high amount of data.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Replace all rows where this `meta_value` has `Red` (hidden somewhere in a comma-separated list) with `Blue`?

Comment: @redskins If you think 70k rows is a "high amount of data" then you shouldn't be commenting here.

Comment: @redskins80: if it was 70,00 rows added per second, then I'd suggest "this is lots of data"

Comment: @redskins80 this is really tiny. I have a MySQL database with over 750 000 000 rows and I still have acceptable performance on the table. It is currently over 500GB big. 70K rows is tiny tiny tiny

Comment: @ypercube in meta_value is big serialized multidimensional PHP array, one key of that array contains info about colors "REd, Blue, Green(+3)". I sometimes need to change that (+3), it is addon price for Green product (it is very annoying and badly writen WP webstore plugin we are talking about).

Comment: Really bad design. No such thing should be stored in a database column. Not if you want to be updating it or doing calculations with it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ways that can help optimizing :

- Try getting the ID besides the meta_value , and when using update just reffering to the ID.
- Check if you really need to use the entire wildcard or you can make it post or prefixed.

Meaning :

```
#Full wildcard  

 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%something%';  

#Postfix wildcard  

 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE  'something%';  

 #Prefix wildcard  

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE  '%something';
```

- Make sure you're using the right data types, that varchars are the right size, using int instead of BigInt, etc.
- Try moving the query to a Stored Procedure, Stored Procedures are compiled (SQL Code is not), making them faster than SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting an index on 'meta_key' and try to work around having to use LIKE for these operations. Why do you  need LIKE here? What's the exact requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Besides storing the primary keys from the first query and using them in the update, you could, make a temporary table, do a batch insert to that table and then a join update on the primary table.

That way, you won't have to run a query in a cycle.

[Creating Temporary Tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a php person, but on sql side I can suggest you something. There are some things that you can do,

Your SQL statement is,

SELECT meta_value FROM my_table WHERE meta_key = 'key' AND meta_value LIKE '%something%'

The things that you can do are,

1. Add indexes on the key filed.
   There are two filed in your query meta_key, meta_value, try adding composite or separate indexes for both.
2. The query
   Now check which clause in your where block returns more rows. put that before other one.

   Q1 : SELECT meta_value FROM my_table WHERE meta_value LIKE '%something%'

   Q2 : SELECT meta_value FROM my_table WHERE meta_key = 'key'

   if Q1 return's more rows than Q2 SQL statement, Then your SQL should be like below,

   SELECT meta_value FROM my_table WHERE meta_value LIKE '%something%' AND meta_key = 'key'